# Convergence of trajectory in an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $x_2(t)$ is continuous and $x_2(t) \rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow \infty,$ $p(\cdot)$ is a polynomial such that $p(0) = 1$ and $p(1) = 0.$ Let $\dot{x}_1 = p(x_2) - x_1.$ Can we conclude that $x_1(t) \rightarrow 1$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Why should it? A more plausible claim is that $x_1(t)\to p(x_2(\infty))=p(0)=1$.

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant. Edited my question. It should be does $x_1(t) \rightarrow 1$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Slightly abusing Taylor polynomials, you get $x_1(t+1)=x_1(t)+\dot x_1(t)+...\approx p(x_2(t))$, so essentially $x_1$ follows "one step" behind $p(x_2(t))$. This implies that their convergence behavior is the same. One can easily take one term more, $x_1(t+1)=x_1(t)+\dot x_1(t)+\frac12\ddot x_1(t)+...\approx \frac12(x_1(t)+p(x_2(t))+p'(x_2(t))\dot x_2(t)))$ (this requires some regularity from the derivative of $x_2$ that is not in the assumptions). I believe that one can make a strict argument in that direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Using Duhamel's formula we get
$$x_1(t)=e^{-t}(x_1(0)+\int_0^t e^s p(x_2(s)) ds)$$
Now, $p(x_2(t)) \rightarrow p(0)=1$ as $t \rightarrow +\infty$. Let us fix $\delta>0$ and $T$ such that $\forall t> T$
$$1-\delta < p(x_2(t)) < 1+\delta$$
Since $\displaystyle\lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty}e^{-t}(x_1(0)+\int_0^T e^s p(x_2(s)) ds)= 0$ we have
$$1-\delta \leq \liminf_{t \rightarrow +\infty} x_1(t) \leq \limsup_{t \rightarrow +\infty} x_1(t) \leq 1+\delta$$
The thesis follows by the arbitrariety of $\delta>0$.